# Properties of intriangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have been googling for hours, but I can't seem to find properties of intriangle that relate to above question. I may be wrong, but I feel as if I am missing something important, so my question is:

Are there any properties of intriangles that are relevent to this question? If there are, what are they or can you point me somewhere I can find information? If not, can you point me in the right direction or give me a hint?

Please do not give me the answer! I would like to solve this on my own.

Thank you.

Comment: A reason why you didn't get any results is that you are dealing with circumcircle, not incircle.

Comment: My bad, i meant intrinanglr, not incircle

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you encounter the term "intriangle"? I have never met it before.

Comment: I knew what an incircle was, so i assumed that 'intriangle' would be a valid term. There were some results on google, but all were talking about perpendicular bisectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Use Law of sines

Further HINT: $${AC\over \sin b}={CB\over \sin a}={AB\over \sin c}=2r$$